# Calcuation of execution time in Milliseconds in VB 6.0

Tags: math, image-processing, vb6

I have finished writing an image encryption function and I want to calculate the time and cpu execution of the function. This code is written in Visual Basic 6.0. Do you have accuracy code to calculate time and cpu spending for this function in VB 6.0?

Comment: Tough to tell what you are asking for, but since you've posted no code it looks like you are asking for someone to write a timer function for you. Here is a link for an example, http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2005/03/01/VB_timer.html. Or if you have code and need help with it please update your question with what you have tried and what part of it is a problem.

Comment: If I remember right, TimeGetTime is pretty accurate, from winmm.dll.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetTickCount() Api

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  YourFunction
End Sub

Private Function YourFunction() As Long
  Dim lngTime As Long
  Dim lngIndex As Long
  'record start
  lngTime = GetTickCount
  'do your thing
  For lngIndex = 1 To 10000
    Caption = CStr(lngIndex)
  Next lngIndex
  'record passed time
  lngTime = GetTickCount - lngTime
  Print "execution took " & CStr(lngTime); " ms"
End Function
```

Pay attention though that the resolution of the cpu timer isnt accurate enough for ms measurements